# Example of regular space for which exist two distinct points that can not separate by continuous function

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

In the book "General topology" by Engelking, where is exercise to build regular topological space, for which there exist two distinct points, $a$ and $b$, for which is correct sentence: for every real valued continuous function $f(a)=f(b)$ (exercise 2.7.17. page 119).

There is also hint, that such space may build from adjoin the point for the space, which is build by A. MYSIOR, which is regular and not completely regular space. But, I still can`t prove that exercise. please. help me if you can.

Comment: Which nomenclature does Engelking use? Is a regular space a fortiori Hausdorff?

Comment: Yes, suppose regularity means that it is Hausdorff too. Same is Written in that article by Mysior: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-081-04/S0002-9939-1981-0601748-4/S0002-9939-1981-0601748-4.pdf
In first page there is built the regular (and hausdorff also) space that is not completely regular and in second page, is the remark, that if we adjoin one point (with its neighborhoodsto the space from first page, the result space will be also regular, but there will be two points, a and b, that cant separate by continuous function, which means that the result space isn`t completely Hausedorff.

Comment: But, I cant prove that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take Y as in the remark of the article by A.Mysior you have linked. I will follow its notations.

As it is said in the article, Y is regular.
Now take any real valued continuous function $f$ on Y. 
For $\epsilon >0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $U_N(b) \subset f^{-1}([f(b)- \epsilon , f(b) + \epsilon])$ (because since f is continuous, $f^{-1}([f(b)- \epsilon , f(b) + \epsilon])$ is a neighborhood of $b$) .
Set $J_n = f^{-1}([f(b)- \epsilon , f(b) + \epsilon]) \cap \{(x,0) \ | \ n-1\leq x \leq n \}$, since $J_{-N-1}$ is infinite, you can apply the same inductive reasoning as in the article (where it is done for $K_n$), hence $J_n$ is infinite $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
By continuity, we get $a \in f^{-1}([f(b)- \epsilon , f(b) + \epsilon])$.
Thus $f(a)=f(b)$.

I hope this can help.

Comment: Thank a lot. Your last step, when you write that f(a)=f(b), is the reason of that efsilion is arbitrary, yes?

Comment: Yes, exactly, we get $f(a)=f(b)$ since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.